# How to test static void functions using Powermock easyMock?

Tags: java, junit, powermock, easymock

I have a static function that returns void.

This function performs some operation and populates a map internally.

Something like this...

```
public static void doSomething(arg1,arg2,arg3) {
    //Do some processing with the input parameters

    if(arg1 satisfies given condition) {
        //Create object
        Conn conn = new Conn()

        Map<String, List<String>> map = new Map();

        //Populate the map with the processed value

        conn.setAttributes(map);
    }
}
```

Now I want to test if the condition is satisfied whether my 'map' in 'conn' object is populated with the expected values or not?
Need help on this.

Comment: Could you please edit the post so that can be tested? Look here for more information -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I can't post the exact code, All I can say is, this is the scenario that I am facing, and I need to write test cases for the same. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't need the exact test cases either, just a way to approach.

Comment: Well, testing with JUnit a method like your is not difficult, you just create a `@Test` annotation in a Junit class. The problem is that it's not clear what exactly is your question. I can't figure what you are asking. How to use Junit?

Comment: I have this doSomething method that doesn't returns anything, It only updates the conn object with setAttribute method when the if condition is satisfied. I want to test if the condition is satisfied 'conn' object attributes should be set otherwise not.

Comment: In this case you must make the conn variable accessible somehow, and then you can verify it with JUnit with `Assert.assertEquals(getMapValue(), actualValue);`

Comment: As Tim says, your real issue here is the `new()`. All these things are nicely documented: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockconstructor ... but just wondering: when you are not allowed to change code, what happens when you find a bug?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the *hidden dependency*, the instantiation of the `Conn` object.

As a rule of thumb *business code* should not be responsible for aquiering dependencies it has to comunicate with.

You have two solutions:

1. Surrender to your bad design and use <strike>Powermock</strike> to inject a Mock of `Conn`.
2. Improve your design and use *dependency injection/inversion of control*.

   This can be done by simply replace the inner instantiation of the `Conn` object with an additional Parameter of type `Conn`.

   But even better would be to turn your `static` method into a regular non-static member method and pass the instance of `Conn` as Constructor parameter to be held in a `private final` member variable.

   Given that class `Conn` is not `final` you can use regual mocking frmeworks to create mocks of `Conn`  and use that in your UnitTests.

Comment: Solution 2 is out of question as I am not authorized to alter the design(business regulations). Now coming to Solution 1, I had already tried that but I want to perform of some assertions like..."assert(conn.getAttributes.containsKey("key"));" I had mocked the class in which 'doSomething' is available and mocked all required parameters as well, But I am not sure how to retrieve that conn object so that I can use it in my assertions as shown.

Comment: @NaveenYadav *"Solution 2 is out of question as I am not authorized to alter the design(business regulations)."* Then you should escalate to the project manager that this design is brittle and potentionally slows down future developement. Also you should make clear to her that writing *UnitTests* is a *developer task* not something a "dedicated Tester" should do. I know that this will cause trouble but as a professional you should make any effort to improve the code base.

Comment: @NaveenYadav *"Now coming to Solution 1"* I know that this will cause downvotes, but I strongly discurage using PowerMock. And since I don't use it myself I neither can nor want to help here.